# qt QCustomplot, сборка. Не найдена точка входа

Tags: c++, qt

Приятного времени суток. Решил разобраться с постройкой графиков используя QCustomPlot.

Статья примера http://blog.harrix.org/article/1813
Делал всё 1 в 1(поменял ввод данных и функцию).
При отладке и сборке через Qt Creator в конце открывается окно моего приложения и всё работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я захожу в папку release и пытаюсь открыть его, выдаёт сообщение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашёл эту .dll в папке Qt, вставил в корень release, но получаю очередные сообщения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно вы скопировали не ту библиотеку с которой компилировали, например взяли debug вместо release. Или не той версии.

Comment: да, вы правы, я брал из папки bin, но на диске C: в загрузках нашлись какие то "левые" загрузки где я и нашёл работающую либу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

правильную библиотеку я нашёл в C:\Users...\Downloads\tools\lib\qt\lib, эта папка у меня около полугода висит с момента настройки компиляции под Android из qtcreator(вроде ant ставил).

как оказалось если поискать во всём диске C:, то будет даже из чего выбрать.
Странность в том что C:\Qt\5.9.1\mingw53_32\bin\qt5printsupport.dll не работала.